# Mysql text field contains both <p> and <img>: How to loop through just <img>?

Tags: php, mysql, image, loops

I'm working on a CRUD project, where database content is mainly being generated with rich text editor (WYSIWYG).

One of MySQL columns is named "content" (data type: text) and it consists of entries with both p and img tags.

To give you example, each entry in that column looks something like this:

`<img src="img/1.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><img src="2.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><img src="img/3.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>`

After SQL statement I can access particular entry above using PHP ($entry = row['content']).

**Question**: How can I loop through every single image in that entry, accessing it's src?

*The reason I need this is - Im currently developing the delete functionality and so far I can remove just database entry, leaving physical files (images) on the server, while i want them to be deleted with the post.

Comment: Parse it with `DOMDocument`.

Comment: thanks, i will look into that!

Comment: @911madza if you are sure that column contain only p or img you can use also regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as suggested by @barmar with DOMDocument:

```
$html = '<img src="img/1.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><img src="2.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><img src="img/3.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>';
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$imgs=  $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $imgs) {
    echo $imgs->getAttribute('src'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: @Barmar and Andrea Manzi got it working, thanks guys.. just curious what is PHP_EOL used for, as i tried it without and it still works

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regexp

```
$row = '<img src="img/1.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><img src="2.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><img src="img/3.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>';

preg_match_all('/src="([^"]+)"/', $row, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input guys @OsDev and Adam, solved it with DOMDocument, tho learned a bit today on how to solve it with elegant one-liner, which might come handy sometime :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular expressions to get this information like this

```php
$data = '<img src="img/1.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><img src="2.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><img src="img/3.jpg"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>';

preg_match_all('/src="(.*?)"/',$data,$matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

This will gives you something like this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "img/1.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "2.jpg"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "img/3.jpg"
}
```

Note that we use `$matches[1]` because is the second offset captured value in the regular expression.

Check and play with the regular expression here

https://regex101.com/r/EVXAWb/1